# How to get differential equation of Fermat Principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, variational-analysis

I've found this file
https://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys3210/phys3210_sp15/Notes/NDSolve_Fermat.pdf

And it says path of beam from Fermat's Principle can solved from

$$\dfrac{n'}{n}=\dfrac{y''^2}{1+y'}$$

How can you get such an equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n,c$ are respectively the index of refraction and the speed of light in vacuum, we have

$$
v = c/n = \frac{ds}{dt} \Rightarrow dt = \frac{n(s)}{c}ds
$$

where $s$ parameterizes $(x(s),y(s))$ the light path across the medium where $s$ is the path length. Then

$$
T = \int_{\Gamma}\frac{n(s)}{c}ds
$$

but here

$$
\frac{ds}{dx} = \sqrt{1+(y')^2}{}
$$

then

$$
T = \frac{1}{c}\int_{s_1}^{s_2}n(y)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx
$$

Now applying the Euler conditions, with $F(y,y') = n(y)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$

we get

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = 0
$$

gives

$$
n(y)y''-n'(y)(1-(y')^2) = 0
$$

Comment: I am trying to follow your derivation and having a little bit of difficulty.  I get 

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = n'(y)\sqrt{1+(y')^2} $$

where $ n' = \frac{dn}{dy} $

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = n(y) \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} $$

When you say $ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} $ do you really mean $ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} $ ?  When I try either I get a much more complicated expression.

Also, do you mean $( 1+(y')^2)$, not $( 1-(y')^2)$ in your final answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Cesar Eo is general and powerful. Here's a derivation with a different flavor.

Many people would not object to start with the [Snell's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) in this form:
$$n \sin\theta = \text{constant}$$
Take the total derivative (implicitly with respect to $y$) and we have
$$\sin\theta \,\mathrm{d}n + n \cos\theta = 0 \quad\implies \frac1{n}\,\mathrm{d}n = -\cot\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta$$
As the pdf file describes `n[y_]:= 1 + β y`, the refractive index changes only vertically (function of $y$ only), which means the layers of "interface" are horizontal. Therefore, the incidence angle $\theta$ is with respect to the vertical (as opposed to the usual $y' = \tan\phi$ where the angle is with $\hat{x}$).
$$\cot\theta = y' \qquad  \text{(see figure at the end with explanation)}$$
\begin{align*}
\text{or} \qquad\theta = \cot^{-1} y'\implies \qquad\frac{ \mathrm{d}\theta }{\mathrm{d}y} &= \frac{-1}{1 + y'^2} \cdot \frac{ \mathrm{d} y' }{\mathrm{d}x} \cdot\frac{ \mathrm{d}x }{\mathrm{d}y} \\
&= \frac{ -y'' }{ 1 + y'^2} \frac1{y'}  
\end{align*}
Put things back together
$$\frac1{n} \frac{ \mathrm{d}n }{ \mathrm{d}y } = -\cot\theta \frac{ \mathrm{d}\theta }{ \mathrm{d}y } = -y' \cdot \frac{ -y'' }{ 1 + y'^2} \frac1{y'} = \frac{ y'' }{ 1 + y'^2}$$
we have the `D[n[y[x]], y[x]] / n[y[x]]== y''[x] /( 1 + y'[x]^2)` in the pdf file. (yes, there is a typo in the question post)

---

[image]

These two diagrams illustrate the fact that $\cot\theta = y'$. The left plot shows an overview of a curve (green) and its tangent line (black) at an arbitrary point $(x_0, y_0)$. The right plot is the zoomed-in exaggerated view around the tangent point.

Consider the finite sized right triangle with a horizontal leg of given length $\Delta x$. It's vertical leg can be approximated by $\Delta y \approx y' \cdot \Delta x$ where $y'$ is evaluated at $x_0$. This is just by definition of $y' \equiv \lim \Delta y / \Delta x$.

Upon taking the limit $\Delta x \to \mathrm{d}x \to 0$, the approximation becomes equality.

Note: although the figure shows a steep tangent line (shorter $\Delta x$ and longer $\Delta y$), the geometry is the same in general, including near-flat tangent as well as negative tangent ($y'<0$).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i can't grasp why $Cot\theta = y'$

Comment: @Ralnor I added a diagram and hope it helps. This is pretty standard stuff that you can find in many calculus textbooks for non-math majors as well as math majors (i.e. it is not something I personally made up).

Comment: @Ralnor Is there anything you need me to clarify? If my answer has more or less addressed your concerns, then please click on the "accept" (checkmark) to conclude this post and remove it from staying in the queue and clogging the system. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not 100% convinced about 1/y' part in the derivative of the angle. Wolframalpha returns only $−y''/(1+y'^2)$

Comment: Please show me the link of your use of WolframAlpha. Note that it is the total derivative with respect to $y$ and the command to use is `Dt[ . ]` but not just `D[ . ]`

Comment: Oh right. Now Dt[ArcCot[y'[x]], y] returns $-\frac{y''(x) \frac{dx}{dy}}{y'(x)^2+1}$. But how do i Know Dt[x,y]=1/y' ?

Comment: @Ralnor Would you accept [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation)?